# Find volume under curve using polar coordinate

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, polar-coordinates, jacobian

I tied to answer the following questions is about the curve surface $z= f (x, y) = x^2 + y^2$  in the xyz space. 
And the three questions related to each other

A.) 
Find the tangent plane equation at the point $(a, b, a^2+ b^2) $in curved surface z .
The equation of the tangent plane at the point $(a, b, f (a, b)) $ on z is given by the following equation

$Z-f(a,b)=f_x(a,b)(x-a)+f_y(a,b)(x-b)$

So i got

$Z-(a^2+b^2)=2a(x-a)+2b(x-b)$
$2ax+2by-(a^2+b^2)$

2) 
when the tangent plane of the previous question moves pass through the point (0,0,-1). Find The equation for a plane S that contains the contact trajectory.

Tried to put 0,0,-1 to equation in number 1
$-1=-(a^2+b^2)$
$z=1$ is S(?)

But i wasnt so sure what is S plane here and what is the relation with Z?

3. Calculate the volume V of the part surrounded by $z=x^2+y^2 $ and the plane S

Note : 
I was confuse about number 3, what is the area surrounded by S and Z (?)
Since i wasnt so sure about S and Z here

Comment: Well you are supposed to calculate the two planes $S$ and $Z$ from the question 1 and 2, and use it in question 3.

Comment: Yes i got s and z already but i dont know how s and z intersect each other, can you show me the what is the area surrounded by s and z

Comment: @Vik Have you solved this problem? Are you still interested in an answer?